# Does adding a subview also add that view's subviews?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, subview

Say I have a custom `UIImageView` with several `subviews`.

In a `UIViewController`, if I create the custom `imageView` and add it as a `subview` to `self.view`, does that mean all the custom `view`'s `subviews` will display on the screen, or just the custom view without its `subviews`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole view hierarchy: the current view, it's subviews, their subviews, and so on, will be added to `self.view`'s view hierarchy.